# junit 4.11 hangs java 1.7

Tags: junit, java-7

I have the following simple JUnit configuration; compiling and running the code under Java 6 works fine, but compiling and running under Java 7 hangs the application (both under Ubuntu 10.04 and MS Vista).

```
public class TextAreaThread extends Thread {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         JUnitCore junitcore = new JUnitCore();
         MyListener listener = new MyListener();
         junitcore.addListener(listener);
         junitcore.run(CheckerTest.class);
         listener.testRunFinished(null);
         try {
            listener.getRiport();
         } 
         catch (BadLocationException ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
         } 
         catch (IOException ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
     }

}
```

CheckerTest contains only basic methods annotated with @Test:

```
    @Test
    public void checkWellFormed() throws AssertionError {
        fail("failed"); 
    }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
krisy

---

Matthew, the code is as follows:

```
public class Validator extends JFrame {
     public Validator() {
         startMenu.addMenuListener(new MenuListener() {
            @Override
            public void menuSelected(MenuEvent arg0) { 
                    TextAreaThread tframe = new TextAreaThread(textArea, inputXMLPath);
                    tframe.start();
//some other stuff
```

Comment: How are you running this thread? Can you provide that code as well please?

Comment: isn't `listener` notified of the test run having finished by `junitcore.run()`?  Calling the notification again or with `null` might be the cause of your problem -- instead of `null`, pass the result of `junitcore.run()` to `listener.testRunFinished()`

Comment: Attila: you're right; MyListener is notified of finishing the test (modified my code acocrdingly). Still, upon deleting the testRunFinished notification, the application hangs :-(

Comment: Update: I have tracked down the problem to another fail() method, which is simply creates a SAX parser ...I don't know if there is any connection ...?